# Why doesn't the date format of field change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date-format

I am trying to change the date format of a bound field but it doesn't change

ViewModel:

```
        [Required (ErrorMessage="From Date is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.FromDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control searchbox-border", placeholder = "From Date" } })
```

Comment: Show us your editor template, please

Comment: The code you have shown will display the date in the browsers culture

Comment: @StephenMuecke so how to change that?

Comment: You could just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control searchbox-border", placeholder = "From Date" })` with will display a textbox with the formatted date

Comment: @StephenMuecke I checked, it doesn't display the calender

Comment: Of course not. For that you need the code you have in your question. But the whole point of the HTML-5 datepicker is to display the date in the browsers culture

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I did apply the code, and still doesn;t work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172878/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-stacky).